# LD Player adb port number?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, adb

I am a React Native developer.
I used to run my app on Nox.

```
adb connect localhost:62001
react-native run-android --deviceId localhost:62001
```

Now, I want to run my app on LD Player.
However, I don't know what the port number of the LD Player is.

```
adb connect localhost:?????
```

Please help me with how to connect and run my react-native app on LD Player.

Answer (score 0):

LDPlayer doesn't have port naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
adb connect localhost:5554

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).